# test android based bluetooth chat application for multiple user

Tags: android, bluetooth

I just want to add some features in sample bluetooth chat application and want to test its working at each successive level.
since i have limited resources like a laptop and a android based phone. How can i connect two devices to run features that support multiple devices.

I am running android based bluetooth chat application on my android phone.I want to add some features that required bluetooth. The problem is that i am having single android phone right now but i want to check whether it is really connecting to other devices and want to test features that need more than one device. Is their any solution or i need two android phones.